# More than 1 cache manifest file?

Tags: html, manifest, browser-cache

Is it possible to use more than one cache manifest file?

Does the html manifest attribute support more than one file?

If it does, how can i do that?

The idea is to include files in the cache list whitout losing the cache of the earlier files. That's because when we change the manifest file, the files in the list are downloaded again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for a given page you can only have 1 cache manifest file.